# JPA merge foreign key lost

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I'm new to JPA Hibernate implementation and I'm trying to understand how EntityManager.merge works.
I have the following scenario of two classes with @ManyToOne relation e.g

```
class A{
   private String name;
   ........
   get...
   set...
}

class B{
   private String name;

   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
   private A a;
   ........
   get...
   set...
}
```

And I have GUI where you can view and change only B property's - the A class is not loaded and there is no Open Session in View. 
When trying to save(merge) changes in back-end:

```
entityManager.merge(b); //the object "b" created from view has "a" set to null
```

In database in table B the foreign key relationship(referencing to table A) is lost - set  to null;
This is not what a want I want to keep the relationship and merge-save the changes made in the GUI to object B with out losing the Many-To-One relationship
Maybe what I'm expecting is not possible and what I need to do is:

```
 dbB b = entityManager.find(B.class, id);
 dbB.setName(b.getName());
 dbB.set........
 entityManager.merge(dbB);
```

Answer (score 1):

If in `entityManager.merge(b);` the relation `b.a` is null, `merge` will delete the foreign key. That's because the value `null` doesn't mean the reference should be ignored but that the reference should be removed (i.e. there is no reference anymore).

> I want to keep the relationship and merge-save the changes made in the GUI to object B with out losing the Many-To-One relationship

One option would be to read the entity from the database with `a` being initialized to a lazy proxy and pass it to the gui. During that process the entity will most likely get detached and hence you need to merge it during save. However, since `a` won't be null in that case, the reference should not get lost.